# Create a table that is not registered with the geodatabase

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, table, oracle-dbms, objectid

I am doing some testing that requires having a Oracle table that is not registered with the geodatabase. For instance, [Adding an Incrementing ID Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-incrementing-id-field.htm) can only be performed on a table that is not registered with the geodatabase.

How can I create a table this not registered with the geodatabase?

Comment: You can access an Oracle database with the [cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. I often use it to access our SDE database.

Comment: For the record, there is no such thing as an "SDE geodatabase" (geodatabases were introduced with ArcSDE).  This is relevant because there is no need to access **any** database supported by Esri with an additional product, because the `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute()` method can open a SQL cursor on any database, whether enterprise geodatabase enabled or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - how about just creating the table using the standard Oracle tools. For example sqlplus (the command line) using the proper CREATE TABLE syntax ? You obviously have that since you run Oracle.

And as Vince pointed out there are no such things as "geodatabase tables" and "database tables". There are only database tables. A "geodatabase" is just an ESRI concept that physically means the presence of an ESRI-specific dictionary (= a set of tables) where ESRI keeps track of the database tables it uses.

Comment: This will accomplish what I want. I didn't specify in my question, but realize now that what I really want is table without an object ID (since the Adding an Incrementing ID Field tool only works when a incrementing field doesn't already exist). I don't have sqlplus myself, but my IT department will be able to help with this.

Comment: On a side note: If all that's needed is to create an unregistered table, then the Create Unregistered Table geoprocessing tool will accomplish this (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-unregistered-table.htm). I didn't know about it until now.